# how to force a Polymer.Element extended class to execute its lifecycle without attaching it to the dom?

Tags: polymer, lifecycle, polymer-2.x

Consider this element *(minimal for the purpose of the question)* :

```
class MyCountDown extends Polymer.Element
{
  static get is () { return 'my-count-down'; }

  static get properties ()
  {
    return {    

      time: { /* time in seconds */
        type: Number,
        observer: '_startCountDown'
      },

      remains: Number
    }
  }

  _startCountDown ()
  {

    this.remains = this.time;

    this.tickInterval = window.setInterval(() => {
      this.remains--;
      if (this.remains == 0) {
        console.log('countdown!');
        this._stopCountDown();
      }
    }, 1000);
  }


  _stopCountDown () {
    if (this.tickInterval) {
      window.clearInterval(this.tickInterval);
    }
  }
}

customElements.define(MyCountDown.is, MyCountDown);
```

If I get one instance and set the property *time*,

```
let MyCountDown = customElements.get('my-count-down');
let cd = new MyCountDown();
cd.time = 5;
```

the property *time* changes but the *observer* and the **_startCountDown()** function is not called. I believe *Polymer* is waiting for the Instance to be attached to the DOM because in fact when I appendChild() this element to the document the count down starts and after 5 seconds the console logs `'countdown!'` as expected.

---

My goal is to execute this lifecycle without attaching anything to the document because the instances of MyCountDown are not always attached to the view but/and they need to be live-code between the different components of my web application.

**One solution is to attach the new MyCountDown instances to an hidden element of the dom to force the Polymer lifecycle but I think this is not so intuitive.**

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the exact place to call, but the problem you have is that the property assessors are not in place.

I think you might get a clue from this talk https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=assSM3rlvZ8 at google i/o

call `this._enableProperties()` in a constructor callback?